# onChange event is not fired when the browser autofills a password input

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm binding an onChange event to a text input and a password input for a login form.

When the user saves the password into his browser and he comes back to the login page, the browser will autofill the two inputs and only the text input 'onChange' event will be fired. The password event won't be fired, and it's the same if I replace onChange by onInput.

What's the problem here?

Comment: Just tested this on Firefox. Both the `change` and the `input` event works when these two event listeners are added to the password field when the DOMContent is loaded.

Comment: @Xufox Does it also work using Chrome for you?

Comment: I currently don’t have Chrome installed and can’t test it…

Comment: Same problem. Did you solve it?